# Grouping the characters and performing substitution

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace my string based on the values in my dictionary. I want to try this with regular expression.

```
d = { 't':'ch' , 'r' : 'gh'}

s = ' Text to replace '
m = re.search('#a pattern to just get each character ',s)
m.group() # this should get me 'T' 'e' 'x' 't' .....

# how can I replace each character in string S with its corresponding key: value in my          dictionary? I looked at re.sub() but could figure out how it can be used here.
```

I want to generate an output -> Texch cho gheplace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> d = { 't':'ch' , 'r' : 'gh'}
>>> s = ' Text to replace '
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, d))
>>> re.sub(pattern, lambda m: d[m.group()], s)
' Texch cho gheplace '
```

The second argument to the `re.sub` can be a function. The return value of the function is used as a replacement string.

Comment: The program works!! , I trying to understand line 4 here, Could you please tell me what does ->pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, d)) will get you?

Comment: @NBA, Regular expression `t|r` matches `t` or `r`.

Comment: @NBA, The expression is basically similar to `'|'.join(['t', 'r'])`, which yields `t|r`.

Comment: @NBA, `re.escape` was used to escape special characters that have special meaning in regular expression.

Comment: @NBA, `t`, `r` just matches literally (no special meaning); `map(re.escape, d)` returns `['r', 't']` (assuming Python 2.x)

Comment: What if i have to do this other way round. I have d={ 'ch' : 't' ,'gh' :'r' ,'asdg' : 'm'} and I want to get 'Text to replace ' back from the string ' Texch cho gheplace ' . How can this be achieved. The key length might be of various length too.

Comment: @NBA, Please post a separated question if you have another question.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no character in the values of the dictionary appear as a key in the dictionary, then its fairly simple. You can straight away use `str.replace` function, like this

```
for char in d:
    s = s.replace(char, d[char])
print s   # Texch cho gheplace
```

Even simpler, you can use the following and this will work even if the keys appear in any of the values in the dictionary.

```
s, d = ' Text to replace ', { 't':'ch' , 'r' : 'gh'}
print "".join(d.get(char, char) for char in s)    #  Texch cho gheplace
```